# C# LINQ compound ordering on 3 columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an object with many fields, but I want to order on 3 columns (boolean [IsValid], int [Count], and date [CreateDate]), conditionally dependent on the boolean.

Data:

```
|| ID || IsValid || Count || CreateDate  ||
==========================================
|| 1  ||  True   || 3     || 2016-05-01 ||
|| 2  ||  True   || 2     || 2016-07-12 ||
|| 3  ||  False  || NULL  || 2015-06-16 ||
|| 4  ||  False  || 1     || 2015-01-01 ||
```

The order I want is:
1) Valid items first
2) If valid, order by Count, else by CreateDate (essentially `(o.IsValid) ? o.Count : o.CreateDate`, but that didn't work), so that the order would be

```
|| ID || IsValid || Count || CreateDate  ||
==========================================
|| 2  ||  True   || 2     || 2016-07-12 ||
|| 1  ||  True   || 3     || 2016-05-01 ||
|| 4  ||  False  || 1     || 2015-01-01 ||
|| 3  ||  False  || NULL  || 2015-06-16 ||
```

If something was once valid, it could be invalidated again, but would not reset the Count.

I've tried doing things like:

```
db.OrderBy(o => new { o.IsValid, o.Count }).ThenBy(o => new { o.IsValid, o.CreateDate })
```

or

```
db.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsValid).ThenBy(o => new { o.SortOrder, o.CreateDate })
```

and other combinations, but I don't know how to get the ordering to work as desired.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Can you describe how it's not working? Is the sequence returned by (e.g.) that second expression identical in order to `db`? Or do you think you're altering `db` so it has a new order, and will continue to re-order itself when properties change on elements within it? Those methods have no side effects. They *return* an enumeration of the same items, but in a different order.

Comment: What about something like `db.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsValid).ThenBy(o => o.IsValid ? o.Count : 0).ThenBy(o => o.IsValid ? new DateTime(2016,1,1) : o.CreateDate)`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett the `.ThenBy(...)` preserves the first `.OrderBy(..)`, and I know that I'm not actually doing anything to db (just on the results returned by the query), so I'm not sure what you're asking... I want it ordered by IsValid, then by other columns based on IsValid. I've edited my question to make more sense, if that helps?

@juharr I tried doing a ternary, but it didn't work; there was a runtime error. Should it work (i.e. have you tried it and it works)?

Comment: @Daevin Not sure if it will work with EF or whatever Linq to SQL provider you're using, but it does work with Linq to objects (if you use the updated one that has two `ThenBy`s instead of one with an anonymous class (I remembered that its not going to be able to do any meaningful ordering on an anonymous class, thus the reason for the `ThenBy` methods).

Comment: @Daevin I didn't have anything to try because I didn't know what you were asking. You didn't say the problem was the order. You just said something didn't work. This sentence was a red herring: "If something was once valid, it could be invalidated again, but would not reset the Count." As I understand that sentence, it's well beyond the scope of whether item A precedes item B at any given moment.

Comment: Are you querying database? What is `db`? Is it entity framework `DbContext`, or just some C# collection?

Comment: @lorond I've just used db as short-hand from writing the table name over and over. It's an EF DbContext, I'm querying a database table `ValidMediaVisitedByCustomer` (not my design), so more accurately it'd be `db.ValidMediaVisitedByCustomer.OrderBy(...)...`

Comment: @EdPlunkett ah, gotcha. Sorry I wasn't clear enough. It's the ordering that's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because LINQ queries are lazily evaluated, you can accomplish this with a couple of different queries that get concatenated together. I'm not sure how efficient this would be for you, but it accomplishes your goal.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<OrderObject> db = new List<OrderObject> 
        { 
            new OrderObject { Count=1, CreateDate=DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(0)), IsValid=true },
            new OrderObject { Count=2, CreateDate=DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), IsValid=false },
            new OrderObject { Count=3, CreateDate=DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)), IsValid=false },
            new OrderObject { Count=4, CreateDate=DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3)), IsValid=true },
            new OrderObject { Count=5, CreateDate=DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(4)), IsValid=false },
        };

        var validItemsOrderedByCount = (from obj in db
                                        where obj.IsValid
                                        orderby obj.Count
                                        select obj);

        var nonValidItemsOrderedByDateCreated = (from obj in db
                                                 where obj.IsValid == false
                                                 orderby obj.CreateDate
                                                 select obj);

        var combinedList = validItemsOrderedByCount
            .Concat(nonValidItemsOrderedByDateCreated)
            .ToList();
    }
}

class OrderObject
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you prefer LINQ method syntax, this should work.

```
        var validItemsMethodSyntax = db.Where(x => x.IsValid).OrderBy(x => x.Count);

        var nonValidItemsMethodSyntax = db.Where(x => x.IsValid == false).OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate);

        var combinedMethodSyntax = validItemsMethodSyntax
            .Concat(nonValidItemsMethodSyntax)
            .ToList();
```

Or using `Union` and method syntax with one variable as requested.

```
var usingUnion = db.Where(x => x.IsValid)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
    .Union(db.Where(x => x.IsValid == false).OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That would definitely work, but I was hoping to have it in a singular query (despite the lazy-loading being a singular query anyway). I'll keep trying, but if I can't find anything soon, I'll mark yours :) thanks!

Comment: @Daevin This should be the equivalent of doing a Union between two selects.  It's only one trip to the DB and it's unlikely that a single select solution would be any better.

Comment: @juharr I know, I understand how the lazy-loading works, I'm looking for the solution to be a single variable/db action like `db.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` instead of multiple variable/db actions being concat'ed. I can't get into why, but there are reasons. As I said, if I can't find a way to do it how I want, this will be marked as the answer.

Comment: I added an example of how to use the `Union` method to combine everything into one variable. Hopefully that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Zack yeah, that's what I was going to end up doing instead of the `Concat(...)`, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest I could suggest is:

```
db.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsValid)
  .ThenBy(o => o.IsValid ? DbFunctions.AddSeconds(DateTime.MinValue, o.Count) : o.CreateDate)
```

The idea is to convert both columns `CreateDate` and `Count` to same type, then order based on it's value. For linq to objects I would convert both to integral representation:

```
.ThenBy(o => o.IsValid ? o.Count : o.CreateDate.Ticks)
```

but this will not work for EF since there is it cannot map `.Ticks` to sql query. Also I didn't found graceful way to represent `datetime` as integer value, so, another way is to convert existing integer value to `datetime`. Now we have both columns represented as `datetime` and can easily order by it's value.

#### Update

Just did some tests and found that `DbFunctions.AddSeconds(DateTime.MinValue, o.Count)` is represented as `datetime2`, which could be lesser then January 1, 1753 (minimum for `datetime`). Values of this expression are fall in range `[01.01.01 00:00:00 .. 19.01.0069 3:14:07]` but limited by `.Count >= 0` as negative values will produce overflow error.

Let's support negative values for `.Count`:

```
DbFunctions.AddSeconds(new DateTime(70, 1, 1), o.Count)
```

Values of this expression are fall in range `[13.12.0001 20:45:53 .. 20.01.0138 3:14:07]`, which is definitely lesser then `.CreateDate` values (I guess, your min value for `.CreateDate` is in current or past century, i.e. `.CreateDate` is much bigger then `20.01.138`, until you write software in ancient ages). So that is why we could throw `.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsValid)` away.

The final answer to your question is a single `order by`:

```
db.OrderBy(o => o.IsValid
              ? DbFunctions.AddSeconds(new DateTime(70, 1, 1), o.Count)
              : o.CreateDate)
```

Valid values will go first as they will have lesser `datetime2` values, then invalid ones. Valid values will be ordered by ascending `.Count`.

However you could easily manage order direction as well as who goes first, valid or invalid. For example, change year of base date for `.Count` to `7000` instead of `70`, multiply `.Count` by `-1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ternary operators as juharr mentioned in the comments:

```
db.ToList()
    .OrderBy(e => e.IsValid)
    .ThenBy(e => e.IsValid ? e.Count : 0)
    .ThenBy(e => e.IsValid ? DateTime.MinValue : e.CreateDate);
```

Keep in mind that if you are doing any filtering, do it before the `.ToList()` to minimize the results coming back from the data layer.

Comment: This is possible with Entity Framework's LINQ-to-SQL? I tried it, but I got a runtime error.

Comment: @Daevin, yes.  To note, this is not Linq-To-SQL.  The `.ToList()` means that the query is pulled back in memory, then sorted.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: you're right, I missed the "ToList()" at the start. Ideally the filtering would be done by the SQL query to minimize the data returned. But good point, thanks!

Comment: @Daevin, yes, as I mentioned, you would want to do the filtering before the `.ToList()`, but you can do the sorting in memory and not be limited to Linq-To-Entities constraints.